# Model Validation in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am not getting validation messages? Any idea how to resolve? please take a look at the view, the model, and the controller code below. I also attached the js files maybe im missing files?

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Assesment
<link href="../../Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
   @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.name)
   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m=>m.name,"*Hello")

}
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MvcApplication1.Models
{
   public class Assesment
   {   
    [Required]
    public string name { get; set; }
    }
}

public class RegisterController : Controller
{

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult Index(Assesment assesment)
     {
         return View();
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is your submit input outside of the form?

Answer (score 0):

Your `<input type="submit">` should be inside the form.

Also, you should pass the invalid model to the view when handling the POST

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Assesment assesment)
{
    return View(assesment);
}
```

By the way, a typical `HttpPost` action looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(Assesment assesment)
{
    if( ModelState.IsValid )
    {
        // Handle POST data (write to DB, etc.)
        //...
        // Then redirect to a new page
        return RedirectToAction( ... );
    }

    // show the same view again, this time with validation errors
    return View(assesment);
}
```